# Finding the minimum vertex cover of planar graph given the planar representation

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, np-complete, np-hard

The minimum vertex cover problem is $NP$-hard for the planar graph of degree at most $3$. However, the minimum vertex cover can be easily found in some certain types of planar graph, given the planar representation. For example, the planar graph that every face boundary is a cycle of even length.

Is there any proof that shows the $NP$-hardness of the minimum vertex cover of the (general) planar graph, given its planar representation as an auxiliary input?

Answer (score 1):

Given a planar graph, one can always compute a [combinatorial embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_embedding#Combinatorial_embedding) for it.